# Difference between int,input() and int(input())

Tags: python

I discovered that when listing an array, int,input is acceptable than int(input()). Can someone explain it to me what is the difference of this two and why is that the output?

when this is my code:

```
def Union(arr1, arr2):
    res = list(set(arr1) | set(arr2))
    return sorted(res)
 
arr1 = list(map(int(input("Enter first array: ").split())))
arr2 = list(map(int(input("Enter second array: ").split())))
print(Union(arr1, arr2))
```

It outputs:

```
Enter first array: 1 2 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    arr1 = list(map(int(input("Enter first array: ").split())))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Compare to when I use this code

```
def Union(arr1, arr2):
    res = list(set(arr1) | set(arr2))
    return sorted(res)
 
arr1 = list(map(int,input("Enter first array: ").split()))
arr2 = list(map(int,input("Enter second array: ").split()))
print(Union(arr1, arr2))
```

Comment: `int, input` is not something useful. Do you mean `map(int, input())`? Add your code to the question. Add expected behaviour.

Comment: `map()` is doing something significant here that you may be overlooking. Namely, it allows for passing each element of the `list` you create with `.split()` to the `int()` method, which effectively converts each item to an integer and returns a list of each parsed integer. The error in your first attempt is because you are using the result of `.split()` (which is a list) as an argument to the `int()` method (which expects a string).

Comment: the first one makes the output of .split() as an argument to int()? Do I get it? and may I know what does the int in the second code does?

Comment: @beginner `map(int, my_list)` applies the function `int()` to each element of `my_list`. It is equivalent to `[int(x) for x in my_list]`.

Comment: thank you so much everyone, for answering my questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your solutions are doing a lot of things all in one line. Let's break each line into smaller steps to see what it is doing.

We'll start with

```
arr1 = list(map(int,input("Enter first array: ").split()))
```

Now let's look at each piece individually:

```
number_string = input("Enter first array: ") # get input
number_strings = number_string.split()       # split input into a list
numbers = map(int, number_strings)           # convert input to numbers
number_list = list(numbers)                  # make it a list
```

Now let's break down this one:

```
arr1 = list(map(int(input("Enter first array: ").split())))
```

The individual pieces look like this:

```
number_string = input("Enter first array: ") # get input
number_strings = number_string.split()       # split input into a list
number = int(number_strings)                 # convert an entire list to a number????
```

Now we can see why there is an error. You cannot convert a list to an `int`.

Often when you have errors or other issues, it is best to break a long statement into smaller pieces like this. That way you can see which of the smaller steps causes the problem.