# Can you explain what is this? l=list(map(int,input().split()))

Tags: python

I understand this is to take input into a list from user. But what exactly happens in this code?

```
l=list(map(int,input().split()))
```

why map is used? Why `split()` fn is used?

Comment: There are many other questions already posted about this idiom: [Difference between int,input() and int(input())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73693059)

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations is from inside parentheses to outside. So it goes something like this:

1. `input` gets user input from the console
2. [`split` without any args splits by whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
3. `map(int, split_list)` takes a function to execute `int` on each element in the list and returns a new iterator (it doesn't run the function immediately, it's like lazy loading)
4. `list()` Casts that iterator to a list, executes `int` on each item in the list, which casts all items in the list to ints.

So this line gets user input and tries to turn it into a list of ints. It'll fail is you pass in letters.